# Python list add variables in rows

Tags: python-3.x

im trying to add variables to a list that i created. Got a result from a session.execute.
i´ve done this:

```
def machine_id(session, machine_serial):

    stmt_raw = '''
        SELECT
            id
        FROM
            machine
        WHERE 
            machine.serial = :machine_serial_arg
        '''    
    utc_now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    utc_now_iso = pytz.utc.localize(utc_now).isoformat()
        
    utc_start = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(days = 30)
    utc_start_iso = pytz.utc.localize(utc_start).isoformat()
        
    stmt_args = {
        'machine_serial_arg': machine_serial,
        }
        
    stmt = text(stmt_raw).columns(
        #ts_insert = ISODateTime
        )
        
    result = session.execute(stmt, stmt_args)
        
    ts = utc_now_iso
    ts_start = utc_start_iso
    
    ID = []

    for row in result:
        ID.append({
            'id': row[0],
            'ts': ts,
            'ts_start': ts_start,
            })
    return ID
```

In trying to get the result over api like this:

```
def form_response(response, session):
        result_machine_id = machine_id(session, machine_serial)
        if not result_machine_id:
            response['Error'] = 'Seriennummer nicht vorhanden/gefunden'
            return   
        response['id_timerange'] = result_machine_id
```

Output looks fine.

```
{
  "id_timerange": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "ts": "2020-08-13T08:32:25.835055+00:00",
      "ts_start": "2020-07-14T08:32:25.835089+00:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Now i only want the id from it as a parameter for another function**. Problem is i think its not a list. I cant select the first element. result_machine_id[0] result is like the posted Output. I think in my first function i only add ts & ts_start to the first row? Is it possible to add emtpy rows and then add 'ts':ts as value?
Help would be nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly ...

Your output looks like dict. so access its `id_timerange` key which gives you a list. Access the first element which gives you another dict. On this dict you have an `id` key:

```
result_machine_id["id_timerange"][0]["id"]
```

Comment: Yes thank tu response['id'] = result_machine_id[0]["id"] working :D